# Real part of Riemann Zeta function inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

In the book ‘Riemann’s Zeta Function’ by H.M Edwards, the following is a line in a proof (within section 6.7) that I can’t follow. The variable $T$ is just a positive real number.

$$|\Re [\zeta(2+iT)]|\geq 1 - 2^{-2}-3^{-2}-4^{-2}-… = 1 - (\zeta(2)-1)$$

Where does this result come from?

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a proper citation: book author, and *where* in the book is the proof? (Which lemma/theorem, and even page number+line number.)

Comment: I see your edit, but your citation is still incomplete - who is the author? (This makes it *much* easier to find the book!) Also, stating the theorem number is better than a page number, as page numbers can change when new editions come out.

Comment: Hi. I’ve added the author but it is not written as a theorem in the book so I don’t know how to be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes from the fact that
$$\Re\zeta(2+iT)=\Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2+iT}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Re n^{-iT}}{n^2}.$$
Since $n^{-iT}=e^{-iT\log n}=\cos(T\log n)-i\sin(T\log n)$, the numerator of each term is between $-1$ and $1$. The numerator of the $n=1$ term is $1$, so we have
$$\Re\zeta(2+iT)\geq 1-\frac1{2^2}-\frac1{3^2}-\frac1{4^2}-\cdots.$$

Comment: I think need to remove $i$ from arguments of cos and sin. But very helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Andrew23 Good point -- I've made the correction!